# How to output JSON format on Jersey Restful webservice

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-ws

I have added a Jersey library to my application as well as a media JSON library as you can see here:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>click-digital-backend</groupId>
    <artifactId>ClickDigitalBackend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>



    <dependencies>



        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>





    </dependencies>



</project>
```

here I have a simple test method to return a list as JSON:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Path("/devmanager")
public class DeviceManager implements DevManager {
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public MyList getString(){
    List<String> al = new ArrayList();
    al.add ("Hello");
    al.add ("World");
    MyList list = new MyList (al);

    return list;
}

@Path("/string")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getS(){
    return "Hallo";
}
```

and:

```
package devicemanager;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "MyList")
public class MyList {

    List<String> userList;

    public MyList (List<String> lst)
    {
        this.userList = lst;
    }

    //setters and getters goes here
}
```

now I am running the glassfish server v. 4.1.1  but I am getting a 500 error in the browser and on the log it says:

```
[2018-01-07T16:51:38.646+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor] [tid: _ThreadID=34 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1515340298646] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class devicemanager.MyList, genericType=class devicemanager.MyList.]]
```

I have searched for hours now for a solution and tried to include many different libs that should do this JSON formatting but I don't find a solution. Even if I am requesting XML format I am getting the same error.
if anybody could help me find the issue that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define the response `JSON` as `List`, as the `JAXB` is unable to identify the `@XmlRootElement` over the `java.util.List` or `java.util.ArrayList` class definition.

I would suggest to wrap your `List` as follow

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "MyList")
public class MyList {

    @XmlElement(required=true) 
    List<String> userList;

    public MyList (List<String> lst)
    {
       this.userList = lst;
    }

    //setters and getters goes here
}
```

And, in your service implemetation

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public MyList getString(){
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
    al.add ("Hello");
    al.add ("World");
    MyList list = MyList (al);
    return list;
}
```

Also, it is good practice to use generic when declaring any collection instead of raw type to avoid any runtime exception.

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
```

should be

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
```

**==Edited==**

Could you **Add**

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
  </dependency>
```

and **Remove**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: what do mean with the comment "some coding to add list to MyList class object" ? how can i do this?

Comment: @ChinaeduOnwukwe you need to populate list, which you are supposed to declared it inside the class

Comment: could you give an example can't figure out what you mean with it

Comment: @ChinaeduOnwukwe I have updated my post. Please note, that is just an example. You can change accordingly. Since, you are writing REST service, so I would assume, you have at least understanding of class and object.

Comment: @ChinaeduOnwukwe I have update class again, please get the latest class and also go through other update.